# Angular 5 bind checkbox true and false

Tags: data-binding, angular5

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

```
<input type="checkbox"
   ng-model="string"
   [name="string"]
   [ng-true-value="expression"]
   [ng-false-value="expression"]
   [ng-change="string"]>
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of this or Angular 5. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple selection,

Here is example from docs

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

See more : https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview